# Cannot assign tasks Workfront API. Getting authentication error

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I'm getting Error: `Request failed with status code 401` when trying to assign tasks. I use `PUT` and  `attask/api/v9.0/task/{task number}/assign` and passing `objID`, `objCode`, `username` and `password` or my ApiKey as params. Fun thing is - it's working through Postman. But it doesn't work in my app deployed on Heroku. Requests with `GET` are working though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the username parameter. Try just invoking   `PUT attask/api/v9.0/task/{task number}/assign?objCode=USER&objCode=<user UUID>&apiKey=<key>`

Comment: Hello Brian, I meant I tried using either credentials or API key. In both cases I'm getting `401` status. Get requests are working fine. I'm using axios: `axios.put('https://{domain}.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v9.0/task/{task number}/assign', { params })`; and params are { apiKey: ***,
            objID: ***,
            objCode: 'USER' }

Comment: I'm not familiar with axios, but I would consider that maybe it's botching the call somehow. Can you have it print out the actual HTTP request it's sending and look at it manually? I usually get a 401 error when my parameters don't encode properly and it isn't able to read my API key. Maybe Axios is formatting PUTs weirdly if GETs are working OK? One last thing - the attask-ondemand.com is deprecated, so consider switching to <domain>.my.workfront.com when you can.

Comment: You are right. The problem was in axios weird formatting of my PUT request parameters. I will switch to the <domain>.my.workfront.com. Thank you.